# Page not found loading deeper Laravel routing

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I can't seem to load a route that goes something like `/articles/create` in Laravel, despite being able to load `/article` or `/article/{id}`. I still get the error:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

When it's clearly there with something as simple as

```
Route::get('/articles/create', function() { 
        return "The Real Slim Shady";   
});
```

EDIT: Also no error in my log, just `[Sun Aug 16 04:39:49 2015] ::1:60349 [200]: /favicon.ico` so nothing interesting.

EDIT:

```
MyComputer:laravel myname$ php artisan route:list
+--------+----------+-----------------+------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI             | Name | Action                                        | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-----------------+------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /               |      | Closure                                       |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | articles        |      | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@index |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | articles/create |      | Closure                                       |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | articles/{id}   |      | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@show  |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | laravel         |      | Closure                                       |            |
+--------+----------+-----------------+------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
```

The route definitely does exist.

EDIT:

I've also tried to change the `.htaccess` per Laravel's instructions about the `mod_rewrite` rules. The only thing I could change was to change `Options -MultiViews` to `Options +FollowSymLinks` but no change.

---

Comment: You have a syntax error on the last row of your route definition (braces should flip places). If that does not solve your problem you need to provide more info as it works as expected for me.

Comment: You're right. There was an error there because I didn't copy past the last part. The syntax on my real code is correct, but I still have the issue. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit; only now see your second update where you listed the artisan route:list output.

The problem is probably related to the sequence of your routes definition.

If you have defined it like this sequence:

```
articles/{id}
articles/create
```

The illuminate router cannot see a difference between a route with an article id `create` and the second definition. In order to tackle this issue, either sort the create route above the idea or define what id should look like.

> Change route order:

```
article/create
article/{id}
```

> or specify what Id should look like

```
Route::get('/articles/{id}', function() { 
    // ..  
})->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much!